# Angular Bootstrap DatePicker UTC wrong output

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, utc

Hello I am using a Angular DatePicker in my application which is working how it is supposed to be. I try working with UTC time and the datepicker is inited with this value:

```
scope.model.value = moment.utc().startOf('day').toDate()
```

This result in this date:

```
Tue Oct 27 2015 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Zeit)
```

If i want to choose now a date e.g.: 1st June 2016 the result of scope.model.value is:

```
"2016-05-31T23:00:00.000Z"
```

Why is my DatePicker changing my date object to another format? 
How can i take care off the output format? And why is the date 31st May when selecting 1st June?

I have tried several approaches like removing the UTC time information. For example:
(https://gist.github.com/weberste/354a3f0a9ea58e0ea0de):

```
(function () {
'use strict';
 angular
.module('myApp')
.directive('datepickerLocaldate', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
  var directive = {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: ['ngModel'],
    link: link
  };
  return directive;

  function link(scope, element, attr, ctrls) {
    var ngModelController = ctrls[0];

    // called with a JavaScript Date object when picked from the datepicker
    ngModelController.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
      // undo the timezone adjustment we did during the formatting
      viewValue.setMinutes(viewValue.getMinutes() - viewValue.getTimezoneOffset());
      // we just want a local date in ISO format
      return viewValue;
    });

    // called with a 'yyyy-mm-dd' string to format
    ngModelController.$formatters.push(function (modelValue) {
      if (!modelValue) {
        return undefined;
      }
      // date constructor will apply timezone deviations from UTC (i.e. if locale is behind UTC 'dt' will be one day behind)
      var dt = new Date(modelValue);
      // 'undo' the timezone offset again (so we end up on the original date again)
      dt.setMinutes(dt.getMinutes() + dt.getTimezoneOffset());
      return dt;
    });
  }
}])
})
```

For those who are coriuos here a snippet how i am using the picker:

```
<datepicker datepicker-localdate ng-model="model.value" min-date="minDate"></datepicker>
```

Maybe someone can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the fix for the calendar issue was:

```
function apply() {
    // create new UTC date object
    // necessary to prevent usage of browser timezone which results in selection of previous day in some cases
    if (scope.model.type === 'calendar') {
      var date = moment(scope.model.value);
      scope.model.value = new Date(Date.UTC(date.format('YYYY'), date.format('MM')-1, date.format('DD')));
    }
```

Hope this helps other guys with this issue!

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

In your app config you can tell globally how you want your dapicker output format to be. eg :

```
datepickerPopupConfig.datepickerPopup = 'dd/MM/yyyy';
```

doc here: [angular boostrap datepicker DOC](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker)

given your app name is "myapp":

```
angular.module('myapp', [
    'ui.bootstrap'
])
.config(function(
        datepickerPopupConfig
    ) {

        datepickerPopupConfig.datepickerPopup = 'dd/MM/yyyy';

    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think this is closee to my solution but i dont use the datePickerPopup, this is why yur solution does not have any affect on my problem.